# How to map one to many relationship with itself

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a table called TERRITORY which has ID, NAME, ID_PARENT_TERRITORY in it. This is in one to many with TERRITORY_WITH_SUBTERRITORIES. Both the columns in TERRITORY_WITH_SUBTERRITORIES are self  foreign key to TERRITORY(Self references). This stores rows like this:

```
TERRITORY: 
ID      NAME        ID_PARENT_TERRITORY
---    ------     ---------------------
1      India        null 
2      Karnataka    1 
3      Bangalore    2
```

```
TERRITORY_WITH_SUBTERRITORIES: 
ID_PARENT_TERRITORY      ID_SUBTERRITORY
---------------------    ------------------ 
1                          2 
2                          3
```

I'm not able to save data to TERRITORY_WITH_SUBTERRITORIES when data is saved to TERRITORY.

The join table I've written is:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = TerritoryDataImpl.class)
@JoinTable(name = "TERRITORY_WITH_SUBTERRITORIES", 
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_SUBTERRITORY"), 
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_parent_territory"))        
private List<Territory> childrenStructures = new ArrayList<Territory>();`
```

After territory collects parentStructure from UI, I've following code to save:

```
territory.getParentTerritorialStructure().getChildrenStructures().add(object);
    entityManager.merge(territory);
```

TerritoryDataImpl:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "territory")
public class TerritoryDataImpl {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Length(max = 50)
  @Column(name = "name", length = 50)
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = TerritoryDataImpl.class)
  @JoinTable(name = "TERRITORY_WITH_SUBTERRITORIES",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_parent_structure"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
          name = "ID_SUBTERRITORY"))
  private List<Territory> childrenStructures = new ArrayList<Territory>();

}
```

Comment: Can you share your model classes for TERRITORY and TERRITORY_WITH_SUBTERRITORIES so that corrections can be made?

Comment: What's the error? Did you try CascadeType PERIST/UPDATE/MERGE?

Comment: @B.K: Model class for TERRITORY is put. There is no model class for TERRITORY_WITH_SUBTERRITORIES, since it is a join table with no extra columns and is self referenced to TERRITORY. So there is only one model class.

Comment: @Stefan K: Is cascade type required? I'm new to JPA. I've got the many to many relations working without Cascade Type. I don't have any error. I can see the insert statement for TERRITORY only. When I load some data to TERRITORY_WITH_SUBTERRITORIES through sql, I can get those rows in  childrenStructures list in JPA. Well, also tried with CascadeType REMOVE, PERSIST and MERGE. It's not working.

Comment: do you see a second SQL statement at all, when you update territorys childStructures?

Comment: @Stefan: No, I don't see insert statement for TERRITORY_WITH_SUBTERRITORIES. As I said, when I load some data to TERRITORY_WITH_SUBTERRITORIES through sql, I can get those rows in childrenStructures list in JPA.

Comment: so when you manually insert / safe data to the table it works? Did you try to change territory`s name? -maybe the transaction isn't committed.

Comment: It works when I manually enter data. What is the relation with territory name? I didn't understand. The row is getting saved to TERRITORY, but not to TERRITORY_WITH_SUBTERRITORIES is the issue.

Comment: If I were you, I created another model named TERRITORY_WITH_SUBTERRITORIES and insert two foreing keys from TERRITORY model as one-to-many relation. And then cascade them update/delete. This solution will be much easier then join table solution.

Comment: Well you merge territory, so it probably became detached before, thus I assumed a new transaction here.

Comment: @B.K.: Thanks a lot for spending time on my question. Finally, got it working. I've posted the solution below.

Comment: @StefanK.: Thanks a lot for spending time on my question. Finally, got it working. I've posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "territory")
    public class TerritoryDataImpl {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial", nullable = false)
      private Long id;

      @Length(max = 50)
      @Column(name = "name", length = 50)
      private String name;

      @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = TerritoryDataImpl.class)
      @Column(name="ID_PARENT_TERRITORY")
      private TerritoryDataImpl parentTerritorialStructure;

      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "territoryStructure", targetEntity = TerritoryDataImpl.class,
          orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
      private List<Territory> childrenStructures = new ArrayList<Territory>();

      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = TerritoryDataImpl.class)
      @JoinTable(name = "TERRITORY_WITH_SUBTERRITORIES",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_parent_structure"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
              name = "ID_SUBTERRITORY"))
      private TerritoryDataImpl territoryStructure;

    }
```

After territory collects parentStructure from UI, I've following code to save:

```
object.setTerritoryStructure(object.getParentTerritorialStructure());
entityManager.merge(territory);
```